# Compile angular code to be able to do innerhtml action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, symfony

```
function campform() {
    $.ajax({url: "{{ path('campform') }}", success: function(result){
        $("#respuesta").html(result);
    }});
}
```

Result has angular code, and it doesn't work, I don't know how do I have to compile result.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background as soon as possible. Manipulating the DOM like that defeats much of the purpose of using AngularJS.

Comment: Many thanks I'm going to check it out !!

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is not angular way :-)

You should use `$http` service for such calls

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $("#respuesta").html(result);
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: I know it, this kind of code is inside of result. the angular tags don't work if they are printed by inner html. I think result has to be compiled to work. but I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: Sorry, I said wrong things, you mean If I print result (it has angular code inside) by this way, the result's angular code is going to work?